# Create post without model in django

Tags: python, django, serialization

Sorry for my english. I new in django, and i want create custom post. I have not model for this and i dont need create it. I cant understand how create normal post reqest in django. Bellow my try create it

view:

```
class CreateCustopPost(generics.GenericAPIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = CustomSerializer
```

serializer:

```
class CustomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type_report = serializers.CharField(max_length=23)
    client_token = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
    year_p_start = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    month_p_start = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    day_p_start = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    year_p_end = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    month_p_end = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    day_p_end = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        model = # i dont have model for this.
        fields = ('type_report', 'client_token', 'year_p_start', 'month_p_start', 'day_p_start',
                  'year_p_end', 'month_p_end', 'day_p_end')
```

my qestion: what need typing in serializer class in **model =** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ModelSerializer` used in case you need to perform some action on model. ModelSerializer automatically create fields that correspond to the Model fields. Since you don't have any model you can use normal `Serializer` class, in this case you dont need to specify model:

```
class CustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    type_report = serializers.CharField(max_length=23)
    client_token = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
    year_p_start = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    month_p_start = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    day_p_start = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    year_p_end = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    month_p_end = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    day_p_end = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: i have error `Class CustomSerializer missing "Meta" attribute`

Comment: @nesalexy are you sure you are using `Serializer` instead of `ModelSerializer`? Nevermind you can specify `Meta` with only `fields` attribute for `Serializer` class. See updates.